# Can we think of rotations in $\mathbb R^3$ as translations in some sense?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-actions

Let $SO(3)$ be the rotation groups with its natural action in $\mathbb R^3$:
$$\vartheta:(A,x)\in SO(3)\times \mathbb R^3\longmapsto Ax\in\mathbb R^3$$
I was asking myselft if this action induce a traslation action:
$$\mathcal t: (u,x)\in\mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R^3\longmapsto u+x$$
The idea is that the lie algebra of $SO(3)$ can be view as vectos in $\mathbb R^3$ with the cross product. But I cannot give explicity the translation action $t$ in terms of $\vartheta$. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the line segment $AB$ with endpoints $(0,0), (0, 1)$ and rotate it by 90 degrees in the $xy$ plane, around the point $(0,0)$.  There is no translation that can be applied to $AB$ and give the last result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The translation group $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the rotation group $SO(3)$ both acts on the same space ($\mathbb{R}^3$) but they are really different. You can form a big group, sometimes called $E(3)$, the Euclidean group, consisting of all translations and rotations and their products, that also acts on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However you can't get a translation as a product of rotations, as is easy to see since all rotations fix the origin. And also not as an infinitesimal linear approximation to a rotation (i.e. as an element of the Lie algebra) since it would translate different elements in different directions rather than in the same direction.

If we interpret elements of the Lie-algebra as vectors rather than movements of space, then the direction of this vector corresponds to the rotation axis of the corresponding rotation, so perpendicular to the movement.

(Edit, I just remembered: the standard definition of the Eucledian group $E(3)$ also contains reflections and this subgroup of orientation preserving elements has a different name: $E_+(3)$ or something like this. You should check Wikipedia)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

Now, denote $exp:\mathfrak s\mathfrak o(3)\to SO(3)$ as the exponential map and fix an element $\exp(u) = A\in SO(3)$ for some $u\in\mathbb R^3$. Consider in $\mathbb R^3$ a change to cilindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ where $\partial/\partial z$ coincides with the vector $u\in \mathbb R^3$. Then, the action of $\vartheta$ can be view as a translation, respect these coordinates, right?

Comment: Yes but it is a bit misleading to think it about it this way. The Lie algebra action of $u$ in these coordinate corresponds to an infinitesimal change in coordinate $\theta$ while leaving the other two fixed. Would we call this an (infinitesimal) translation? Just looking at the coordinates and forgetting that they are cilindrical rather than normal you could say yes. But I would say no for two reasons. One reason is that following that translation long enough will not let you traverse straight path but a a circle.  (ctd in next comment)

Comment: The other one is that letting this translation act on different points of $\mathbb{R}^3$ you get movements in different directions. I.e. (1, 0, 0) in normal coordinatse will (start to) move north, while (0, 1, 0) will move west. The infinitesimal 'translation' thus corresponds simultaniously to movements in multiple directions, while 'ordinary' infinitesimal translations correspond only to movements in one direction